# Boolean Array NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, boolean, primes

I am attempting to create a program that will generate all of the prime numbers between two given integers(A & B) for T cases. I am implementing the Prime Sieve of Eratosthenes. My code is below. I have read that NullPointerException for the line mentioned in code would be a result of me not initialising the Boolean array. However, I thought I had done this here:

```
Boolean[] N = new Boolean[B+1];
```

Therefore, I am confused as to why this Exception is being thrown. I am aware of no other possible cause. What is wrong with my code?

My error and input:

```
1 1 5
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PrimeNumberFinder.main(PrimeNumberFinder.java:27)
```

My Code:

```
class PrimeNumberFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //read the number of cases of the problem to expect from input
        int T = sc.nextInt();

        //complete for every case
        for(int i = 1; i<=T; i++){
            //read the boundaries to find primes between
            int A = sc.nextInt();
            int B = sc.nextInt();
            //create boolean array to store primes, according with the Sieve
            Boolean[] N = new Boolean[B+1];
            //set all values to true
            for(int j = 2; j<=B; j++){
                N[j]=true;
            }
            //test for primes for all elements of 'N'
            for(int k=2; k*k<=B; k++){
                if(N[k]){
                    for(int l = k; l*k<=B; l++){
                        N[l*k]=false;
                    }
                }
            }
            //for all prime elements of N between the desired boundaries(A,B) print
            for(int m = A; m<=B; m++){
                //this is the line(below) for which the error appears: NullPointerException
                if(N[m]){
                    System.out.println(m);
                }else{
                    continue;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're gonna use Arrays, `boolean[]` (default value is `false`). Anyway, the issue is that `(boolean)((Boolean)null)` results in an NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created an array of `Boolean` objects, but they are all initialized to `null`.  You do explicitly initialize most of the elements to `true`, but only starting at index `2`.

Assuming this is the line with the NPE:

```
if(N[m]){
```

`m` starts at `A` which appears to be `1` based on the input you gave.  But that was never initialized.  The number `1` is neither prime nor composite, so you should handle this case separately.

Comment: It works when I add special cases for index 0 and 1. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding **Array of objects**, try initializing like this:

```
Boolean[] N = new Boolean[B+1];
for(int i=0;i<B+1;i++)
   N[i]=new Boolean();
```